# MSSQL Exclude primary key in group by

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PAT07, PAT08, PAT18) AS TotalPerPerson
FROM Table1
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4
```

It returns a table that looks like:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   TotalPerPerson
data1  data2  data3  data4  2
data1  data2  data3  data5  2
data10 data11 data12 data13 3
data10 data11 data12 data14 3
data10 data11 data12 data15 3
```

The problem is that this query is in a with clause, and I have no way of joining this to the primary query.  I need to select the "id" column in this query so I can use it in the inner join.  How can I do that without adding the id to the group by?

Comment: You need to add it to the group by or an aggregate. You could try min() or max() or you could use a subquery to select a top 1. Without knowing how the primary key relates to this data it is hard to suggest the best answer.

Comment: combining a `group by` with a window function seems strange. Do you really need the `group by`, especially as you use that in a CTE.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if I don't have the group by then the TotalPerPerson column will count similar records too.

Comment: @liebs19 can you provide an example of a subquery?

Comment: Then extend the `partition by` to only count the distinct ones. Then you can easily add the ID.

Comment: How can I change it for distinct columns?  It doesn't like it if I change it to "partition by distinct ...".

Comment: Something like `SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PAT07, PAT08, PAT18) AS TotalPerPerson, (select top 1 id from Table1 where {criteria relating data to id}) as id
FROM Table1
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4` Its hard to suggest the where clause as I'm not sure how this relates to the data you gave in the question.

Comment: @liebs19 I do not think I need the subquery to select the id from the table.  I need to be able to select the id column, but not use it in the group by or aggregate.  I thought you could do that by using a subquery?

Comment: When grouping all fields need to be in the group by or an aggregate of some sort. The subquery I gave you will select the id based on the where clause you give it relating to Table1 in the outside query.

Comment: @liebs19 if you want to answer the question with your subquery example I'll accept it as the answer.  It did what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to the group by or an aggregate. You could try min() or max() or you could use a subquery to select a top 1. Without knowing how the primary key relates to this data it is hard to suggest the best answer.

For the subquery, try something like:

```
 SELECT 
 col1
,col2
,col3
,col4
,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PAT07, PAT08, PAT18) AS TotalPerPerson
,(select top 1 id from Table1 where {criteria relating data to id}) as id 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY 
 col1
,col2
,col3
,col4
```

Its hard to suggest the where clause as I'm not sure how this relates to the data you gave in the question